# My Imageview on top of uiview is not responding to touch events

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

```
viewImageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:viewImage];
viewImageView.center=self.center;
[[self superview] addSubview:viewImageView];
```

I have added imageview to `superview.self` is `UIView` subclass. But when I Tap or scroll from right to left `touchesbegin: withEvent:` and `touchesEnded:withEvent:` are called. But when I Tap or move from left to right.. `touchesEnded:withEvent:` are not called.It is calling `touchesCancelled:withEvent:` Please help me in fixing this issue.

Comment: I am not able to edit.please edit the question

Comment: Maybe just try viewImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

Comment: I have code like this - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event                                    {                                                                       UITouch* touch=[touches anyObject];m_cTouchStartPoint = [touch locationInView:self];//             longPressRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;viewImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;                        }

Comment: that didnt fix actually

Comment: By default on uiimageview user interaction is disabled.
You need to to enable interaction after initializing your imgaeView object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
[[self superview] addSubview:viewImageView];
```

Try this:

```
[[self view] addSubview:viewImageView];
```

Comment: My class is a subclass of uiview.. How to add in [self view]?